# Correctly setting linker flags using CMake

Tags: c, linker, cmake

I have a project with C and ASM (AT&T) source files that needs a linker script. My `CMakeLists.txt` looks something like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.4)
project(proj C ASM-ATT)
file(GLOB SOURCE_FILES *.c *.S)
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -m32 -Wall -g -fno-stack-protector -pedantic")

add_executable(proj ${SOURCE_FILES})

set_target_properties(proj PROPERTIES LINK_FLAGS "-T${proj_SOURCE_DIR}/link.ld -melf_i386")
```

Strangely enough, building with `make VERBOSE=1` reveals the following:

```
[ 14%] Linking C executable proj
(...)
/usr/bin/cc -m32 -Wall -g -fno-stack-protector -pedantic  -T/path/to/link.ld -melf_i386 (all object files)
cc: error: unrecognized command line option '-melf_i386'
```

It seems that CMake is trying to use `/usr/bin/cc` as a C linker. I have played around with this and tried several different options (including setting `CMAKE_LINKER` and `CMAKE_EXE_LINK_OPTIONS`).

Also note that `CMakeCache.txt` contains a line saying

```
CMAKE_LINKER:FILEPATH=/usr/bin/ld
```

so it obviously is aware of `ld` and is simply using the C compiler to link the executable.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CMake by default invokes the linker indirectly through the compiler executable. The template command for linking executables is set up in the variable [CMAKE_LANG_LINK_EXECUTABLE](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_LANG_LINK_EXECUTABLE.html).

To have the compiler pass the flags on to the linker, use `-Wl` upon setting `LINK_FLAGS`, i.e.:

```
set_target_properties(
  proj PROPERTIES LINK_FLAGS "-Wl,-T${proj_SOURCE_DIR}/link.ld,-melf_i386")
```